# Is TCP/IP required to connect to SQL Server 2008R2 with ODBC over a LAN *NOT* the internet

Tags: sql-server-2008, configuration, odbc

I have read [one](https://serverfault.com/questions/227544/sql-server-connecting-issue) [two](https://serverfault.com/questions/37309/connecting-remotely-to-an-sql-server-inside-a-lan) [three](https://serverfault.com/questions/328308/error-connecting-to-sql-server-2008-express-over-a-lan) related threads but im not clear if SQL Server 2008 needs TCP/IP to make this work. Can it not accomplish with a pipe? I would prefer not to open up the machine to the internet just to test my development machine Win7 and the server WS2008R2 for testing model and ETL performance.

My app uses a connection string:
Driver={SQL SERVER}; SERVER=myserver; Database=test; Uid=mike; Pwd=password;

but i get "dialog error" returned from ODBC (C++)

I found a [nice tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx) on setting up TCP/IP but is this the answer?

ADDED:

OK well I began with [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281850.aspx) which says:
"The shared memory protocol cannot be enabled for remote connections."
After enabling TCP/IP and VIA (whatever that is) I was instructed to restart the server.

Using Cinfiguration managere and then a restart, the service "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)" will not start....

Server log shows
"THE SQL Server failed to intialize VIA support library ..indicates library does not exist"

Is VIA required as [this article](http://www.byteblocks.com/post/2009/04/02/Configure-SQL-Server-to-allow-remote-connections.aspx) suggests?

ADDED:

No it isnt! Follow the instructions [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx) and use the connection string above and you will be good. Sheesh what a pain. I wasted 12 hours on this simple stuff, so if you feel this question saved you that much time, please feel free vote it up.

Comment: You should really consider reviewing the [OSI Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model). No TCP/IP, no SQL ODBC connection.

Comment: Disable VIA, you don't need it.

Answer (score 4):

TCP/IP is required for you to use a TCP network to connect to a SQL Server. You do not have to use a network to connect to the server if you are connecting from the same machine. If you do use a network you do not have to use the Internet. Most modern networks use a protocol called IP - this includes the largest public network known as the Internet. TCP is a protocol build on top of IP that is used to provide additional features on top of IP which are very handy for doing things across a network - like connecting to a database.

TCP: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol
Internet: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet

Comment: Is there no clever way to use a pipe across the LAN?

Comment: The server that SQL is installed on needs a transport protocol in order for you to connect to SQL using any SQL connection type. At the end of the day, SQL server is dependent on the transport protocol of the host OS, which today is TCP/IP in probably 99.9% of cases.

Comment: @Ram: TCP and IP are independent yet interdependent components of the Internet Protocol Suite. TCP is not built on top of IP (although it sits one layer higher in the OSI Model than IP). TCP is concerned with transport (layer 4) and IP is concerned with routing (layer 3).

Comment: @joeqwerty: fair enough... should've said TCP is a protocol used on top of IP... I did not mean to imply that IP is a base component but only that it typically underlies it.

Comment: No harm, no foul. I just wanted to clarify.